# C# Events handling problem for base and derived classes

Tags: c#, events, static, event-handling, derived-class

I have this case where I'm creating 2 different event handlers placed in a base class and subscribing to them accordingly from Quotes and Charts classes. Problem I'm having is that the first subscription triggers fine for the first event but any following subscriptions don't get executed. I have included an example of 2 different handlers, Quotes and Charts, Quotes executes first time with no problems, but Charts does not trigger when data is received.

Base Class:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    protected virtual void RaiseOnQuoteData(string item) { }
    protected virtual void RaiseOnChartData(string item) { }

    void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item == "QUOTE")
            RaiseOnQuoteData(e.Item);
        else if (e.Item == "CHART")
            RaiseOnChartData(e.Item);
    }
}
```

Quote and Chart Classes:

```
public class Quote : MyBaseClass
{
    public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs<quoteRecord>> OnQuoteData;

    protected override void RaiseOnQuoteData(string item)
    {
        OnQuoteData.Raise<DataEventArgs<quoteRecord>>(this, new DataEventArgs<quoteRecord>(item));
    }
}

public class Chart : MyBaseClass
{
    public event EventHandler<DataEventArgs<chartRecord>> OnChartData;

    protected override void RaiseOnChartData(string item)
    {
        OnChartData.Raise<DataEventArgs<chartRecord>>(this, new DataEventArgs<chartRecord>(item));
    }
}
```

Subscription:

```
public class QuoteSubscription
{
    public static void SubscribetoQuoteData()
    {
        Quote Q = new Quote();
        Q.OnQuoteData += new EventHandler<DataEventArgs<quoteRecord>>(q_OnQuoteData);
    }

    static void q_OnQuoteData()
    { 
        //Executes fine
    }
}

public class ChartSubscription
{
    public static void SubscribetoChartData()
    {
        Chart C = new Chart();
        C.OnChartData += new EventHandler<DataEventArgs<chartRecord>>(q_OnChartData);
    }

    static void q_OnChartData()
    {
        //Does not execute
    }
}
```

This is implemented in ASP.NET 4.0, Is there any chance that instantiating the derived classes could be the problem since both classes do share the same base class? Any help pointing to the cause would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need `RaiseOnQuoteData` to be virtual at all?

Comment: The common base class should not be a problem. Could you try to set a breakpoint and check whether `RaiseOnQuoteData` and `RaiseOnChartData` are called when you expect it?

Comment: Did you check that the objects are still alive when the event happens ? (i.e. put a brakepoint in OnDataReceived)

Comment: How does this compile?  The event handlers have no arguments, C.OnChartData is subscribed with the wrong type argument (quoteRecord instead of chartRecord).

Comment: @Vlad How am I supposed to bubble up the event from the base class into the derived class without overriding it if its not virtual?

Comment: @Vlad Both RaiseOnQuoteData and RaiseOnChartData are called but when RaiseOnChartData is called in the base class it simply does not bubble up to the handler in the Chart class.

Comment: @yochai-timmer Both objects are alive when OnDataReceived is executed.

Comment: @hans-passant Mistake after masking sensitive code when copying it to here. It compiles and runs with no problem.

Comment: @Maya: you could override `OnDataReceived`, and have no `RaiseOn*Data` at all.

Comment: @Maya: what do you mean by "doesn't bubble up"? The subscribed method is not called? Maybe you should check whether you (1) subscribed properly, and (2) didn't unsubscribe.

Comment: @Vlad What I meant is that in the code above, in the base class, last thing gets tracked in my debugger is the line where RaiseOnChartData(e.Item) gets called, right after the else if statement, after that nothing happens. What you see in the code is pretty much everything, that's why I posted it here to see of someone thinks I didnt subscribe properly.

Comment: @Vlad As for your first note, I see what you mean now, but the reason I made it virtual in the base class is to let the OnDataReceived decides what type it is so it can decide which event to bubble up to.

Comment: @Maya: what is in `Raise`? This must be an extension method, since `EventHandler` per se [doesn't define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) such a method. Therefore, you can put a breakpoint inside and see, what's going on. (And you could perhaps put a breakpoint inside `RaiseOnChartData` as well.)

Comment: @Vlad You are a star! Raise actually does check if the handler is null so it does nothing, I have checked my code and found that a new instance of the internal handler is created when a new derived class is instantiated, so Raise does nothing after all. A big +1. If you post this is as an answer instead of a comment I will be more than happy to mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is there in Raise? This must be an extension method, since `EventHandler` per se doesn't define such a method. Therefore, you can put a breakpoint inside and see, what's going on. (And you could perhaps put a breakpoint inside `RaiseOnChartData` as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are creating the object within the method scope and has gone out of scope. You may get the first message by coincidence just because it hasn't been GC-ed. Try creating the quote and chart objects as static class member object

Comment: This requires a substantial redesign of the application as static classes cannot derive from type, they must derive from object, which leaves me to use composition, i.e. giving Chart and Quote a static instance of the BaseClass.

Comment: I really dont see how this can be substantial changes. 
private static Quote Q;

public static void SubscribetoQuoteData()
    {
        Q = new Quote();
        Q.OnQuoteData += new EventHandler<DataEventArgs<quoteRecord>>(q_OnQuoteData);
    }